# Error establishing a database connection on Bitnami Wordpress Site

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, sftp, website, bitnami

I'm running Wordpress Bitnami website on an ec2 instance.
Operating system is Debian Linux

Earlier today, I noticed my site becoming slow whenever I upload products(Content)
I have done technical research on increasing the speed,so one of the options
was to resize the instance type from t2.micro to t2.xlarge.

Then I restarted the instance, but displayed different IP-address which I pointed
to my DNS A-record.However,when I try to load the site domain address, it displays
"Error establishing a database connection."
So the site is not actually reachable anymore, yet I can access website files from
the FTP Client.

Any Feedback will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. Please ensure all servers are up and running in your instance by running this command `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status`. If the database is not running, please get more info from it's log file (/opt/bitnami/mysql/data or /opt/bitnami/mariadb/data depending on the Bitnami WordPress version you have). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regarding changing IP address, add an elastic IP address. The standard public IP changes when an instance is stopped and starts, but an elastic IP is permanent. Note that the private IP address does not change.

Check your wordpress configuration file wp-config.php to work out that domain / IP you gave for your database. My best guess based on the information provided is your configuration is wrong now that the IP has changed.

If this doesn't help you will need to do more diagnostics, look for appropriate logs, edit your post and add them there.